# How to adjust/revert back the Single Product Page in WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce website, which the current single product page was seems been accidentally adjusted, the layout became bit weird. May I know how can I adjust back to the normal display? Currently, the display will be photo on top, and description at the bottom of the photo instead next to the photo, can anyone advise?

Can I directly overwrite the file from a fresh copy of woocommerce plugin folder to the live folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update the woocommerce plugins or replace the plugin with the new one. But If you want to manually change the design of the single product page then you can copy the template folder of woocommerce plugins to your theme directory and edit the single-product.php file.

Comment: Beside overwrite the live template with fresh copy,any other way that can revert? this is my page, https://buymotorjohor.com/product/benelli-rfs150i-2017/, the description move to below instead next to the photo.